# Статическая и динамическая память в оперативной памяти и в языках программирования

Tags: стек, куча

Есть виды оперативной памяти-статическая и динамическая. Они отличаются физически по своему устройству, динамическая-конденсаторы, статическая-транзисторы.
Дальше, в языках программирования понятия динамическая память - это куча, автоматическая - стек, и статическая память для глобальных переменных и констант. Перечитал весь гугл, но так и не нашел ответа, в какой области физически выделяется память для кучи, стека, глобальных переменных. То есть взаимосвязь между транзисторами/конденсаторами и статической/динамической памятью в языках программирования. Такое чувство, что присутствует подмена понятий, и динамическое выделение памяти в куче, никак не связано с памятью на конденсаторах. Прошу ответить тех, кто действительно хорошо разбирается в теме.

Comment: `Такое чувство, что присутствует подмена понятий` — да, вы действительно смешали всё в кучу у себя в голове.

Comment: Конкретизирую вопрос. Везде пишут, что для кучи выделяется область в оперативной памяти. В какой ее части, динамической или статической?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то физически статическая и динамическая память это `ROM` и `RAM`. На первой записывают `BIOS` (да и то его можно перезаписать обычно), а всё, что относится к программам, лежит сугубо в `RAM` и там исполняется. Так что не мешайте вместе мух и котлет из разных областей знания, даже если они и называются одинаково. Да, а если вы посмотрите на то, как память распределяет операционная система, то там опять будут области, в которые никому нельзя лазить и области, в которых живут конкретные программы и могут там что-то менять. Так что надо разбираться везде отдельно.

Comment: Во всех обычных компьютерах (персоналках, серверах, смартфонах и т.п.), те программы, которые пишут обычные программисты, имеют дело с динамической памятью (DDR) в качестве оперативной памяти (ОЗУ) (если не считать кэша (который реализуется обычно на статике), но   прикладные программы непосредственно с ним не оперируют)